# Fire another onChange event AFTER first one fires

Tags: jquery, onchange, tracking

I am trying to add Google tracking code to an onChange event in a drop-down menu, however, when I change the onChange event through JQuery, nothing posts/loads. The sort is existing there already. I just need to add the tracking code with the value of the selected item from the drop-down menu.

Here is the onChange event I want to add to or change. This sorts product on the page:

```
Html.DropDownList("products-orderby", Model.AvailableSortOptions, new { onchange = "FiltersPushState(this.value);callAjax(this.value,expiretime.value); return false;" })
```

Here is the Script for the Google tracking code I wanted to add or change the onChange event to:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#products-orderby").each(function () {
            var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            $("#products-orderby").attr("onchange", "FiltersPushState(this.value);callAjax(this.value,expiretime.value); return false;  pageTracker._trackEvent('artwork-sort-by', 'sort', products-orderby." + selectedText + ", products-orderby." + selectedValue + ");");
        });

        $("#products-orderby").change(function () {
            var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            $("#products-orderby").attr("onchange", "FiltersPushState(this.value);callAjax(this.value,expiretime.value); return false;  pageTracker._trackEvent('artwork-sort-by', 'sort', products-orderby." + selectedText + ", products-orderby." + selectedValue + ");");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Cheers,

~D

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Sorry I misunderstood your question. You need to uncomment the call to pageTracker (I'm guessing that is the call for google's analytics, in your code was AFTER the return false; so it will never execute)

```js
$(function () {

        $("#products-orderby").change(function () {
         
            var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
              FiltersPushState(this.value);
                callAjax(this.value,expiretime.value);    
                //pageTracker._trackEvent('artwork-sort-by', 'sort', products-orderby." + selectedText + ", products-orderby." + selectedValue + ");
                return false;
        });
    });
    
    
    FiltersPushState = function(par1){
     alert('FiltersPushState ' + par1);
    }
    callAjax = function(par1,par2){
     alert('callAjax func ' + par1 + ' ' + par2);      
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="expiretime"/>
<select id="products-orderby">
<option value=1>1</option>
<option value=2>2</option>
<option value=3>3</option>
<option value=4>4</option>
</select>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/HappyiPhone/0k93Lv0g/

---

Change it to suit your needs.

```js
$(function () {

        $("#products-orderby").change(function () {
         
            var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
            alert('Selected Text is ' + selectedText);
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            $("#products-orderby").attr("onchange", "FiltersPushState(this.value);callAjax(this.value,expiretime.value); return false;  pageTracker._trackEvent('artwork-sort-by', 'sort', products-orderby." + selectedText + ", produc
    });
    
    

ts-orderby." + selectedValue + ");");
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="products-orderby">
<option value=1>1</option>
<option value=2>2</option>
<option value=3>3</option>
<option value=4>4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you, ProgrammerV5, however, that's exactly what I had before. The problem is that the sort code does not post to reorder the items on the page and the Google tracking code never posts to Google.

This is what I had before... below:

Comment: $(function () {
            $("#products-orderby").each(function () {
                var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
                var selectedValue = $(this).val();
                $("#products-orderby").attr("onchange", "pageTracker._trackEvent('artwork-sort-by', 'sort', products-orderby." + selectedText + ", products-orderby." + selectedValue + ");");
            });

Comment: $("#products-orderby").change(function () {
                var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
                var selectedValue = $(this).val();
                $("#products-orderby").attr("onchange", "pageTracker._trackEvent('artwork-sort-by', 'sort', products-orderby." + selectedText + ", products-orderby." + selectedValue + ");");
            });
        });

Comment: Ok, let me see what I can do.

Comment: Thank you so very much, ProgrammerV5!

Comment: If it helped you can mark the answer as the right one :)

Comment: Okay. It works, but it doesn't post again when I select another option the second time from the menu. And the onChange event is blank. It's not posting the Google event info... Unless it's posting to Google without me knowing about it?

Comment: The change event is firing for sure (unless there's some other issue), to be able to see that behavior add an alert('change fired'); statement inside the change event at the top of any code. If you don't see your events posted open your console (CTRL+SHIFT+I and click on console) and search for errors if any.

Comment: Hi Programmerv5...Unfortunately, I checked, and the Google code is not posting.

Comment: This is what I get in Console:
VM3395:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: pageTracker is not defined
    at HTMLSelectElement.eval (eval at <anonymous> (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:1), <anonymous>:10:17)
    at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:22)
    at HTMLSelectElement.v.handle (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:22)

Comment: Ok, that means that the include file for google functions is not there. You need to fix that before you can get that working but it has nothing to do with the change event not triggering it is a totally different issue.

Comment: It looks like I had to create an instance of pageTracker:

pageTracker = _gat._getTrackerByName();

Comment: I haven't implemented google's tracking script so I can't help there. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you again for all of your help! I'll see what happens with Google...